# Installing SyncTeX Library

Tags: forward-inverse-search

An [update](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/commit/5c60ce41567750eebd6136b0a121b4c2e9c82a06) in [Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) stopped bundling the SyncTeX library and instead expects it to be installed from TeXLive.  The problem is, I can't seem to find it; I can only find the `synctex` binary.  I have installed TeXLive through the `install-tl` script.

Trying

```
tlmgr search --global --all synctex.so
```

returns nothing, and the same goes for `synctex_parser.h`.

What I find quite strange too is that various distributions of TeXLive seem to include the SyncTeX library.  For example, the [Arch Linux distribution](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/texlive-bin/files/) has the following SyncTeX files:

```
usr/bin/synctex
usr/include/synctex/
usr/include/synctex/synctex_parser.h
usr/include/synctex/synctex_parser_utils.h
usr/lib/libsynctex.so
usr/lib/libsynctex.so.1
usr/lib/libsynctex.so.1.17.0
usr/lib/pkgconfig/synctex.pc
usr/share/man/man1/synctex.1.gz
usr/share/man/man5/synctex.5.gz
```

So how do I go about install the SyncTeX library?

Comment: The texlive mailing list might be a better place to ask, see tug.org

Comment: Which is your operating system? How did you install TeX Live?

Comment: TeXLive was installed with the `install-tl` script (as mentioned in the question) and I'm on Linux (Arch Linux to be specific)

Comment: In Debian and derivatives there is the `libsynctex1` package shipping `libsynctex.so.1`, but, as you noticed, in Arch Linux that file is provided by the much larger [`texlive-bin`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/texlive-bin/files/) package, that you may not want to install.  A bug in Arch Linux has opened for your specific problem: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/48010